# Grpc.Core.ClientBase Error in IIS when service invoked from Blazor Webassembly app

Tags: c#, grpc, blazor-webassembly, grpc-web

I'm having the following error in the browser console that is not allowing the Blazor Webassembly app to continue consuming the grpc API:

System.ArgumentException: The base-type Grpc.Core.ClientBase for service-proxy CalibrationSaaS.Application.Services.IBasicsServices`1[ProtoBuf.Grpc.CallContext] lacks a suitable CallInvoker API

The code where this is happening is the following:

var httpClient = new HttpClient(new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()));

```
   using (var channel = Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel.ForAddress(builder.Configuration["Kestrel:Endpoints:Http3:Url"], new GrpcChannelOptions
    {
        HttpClient = httpClient
    }))
    {                
        var a = channel.CreateGrpcService<Application.Services.IBasicsServices<CallContext>>(); //The error happens in this line of code
        var b = await a.GetRoles(CallContext.Default); //This method is implemented
        return b;
    }
```

**This error only happens when the application is published in the respective IIS**, in the development IDE debug environment works normally.

Does anyone have an idea about what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a third party library issue (protobuf-net) that was fixed promptly by his creator. If you need more information you can check this thread:

https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/issues/247

To fix this, update the library to the version to 1.0.171 from Github
and add to the Blazor project file the following configuration:

```
<PropertyGroup> 
...
<BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>false</BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking> 
...
</PropertyGroup>
```